# Decorative tile piece

Tags: tile

My contractor forgot to add a decorative piece of tile to my project he says that he can do this after the project is complete? Is this possible?

Comment: What type of tile, size, shape?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. If it's the same size as the rest of the tiles he'll just knock out some and put in your decorative piece. If it's a irregular tile, he'll trace it where it should go and just cut out the shape with a hand held tile saw.